# how to display date and time from oracle database jee application

Tags: oracle

I'm trying to display data from database ( two different tables) where two columns are type date. I have a problem with formatting: I need to get date and time but I'm getting date and 00:00:00 for time.   Does any one know how to use to_char: I tried this but it doesn't work (query laid out for readability in SO):

```
query.append("SELECT CONCAT(ins.id,'_'
                         ,com.compte,'_'
                         ,com.cin,'_'
                         ,com.nomAff,'_'
                         ,ins.to_char(dateDemande,'DD/MM/YYYY HH:MI:SS ') ,'_'
                         ,ins.typeTPEdemande ,'_'
                         ,ins.statut,'_'
                         ,ins.to_char(dateStatut,'DD/MM/YYYY HH:MI:SS '))   
             FROM InstallationTPE  ins , Commercant com 
            WHERE com.compte=ins.compte 
            AND ins.statut = ?");
```

Thank you

Comment: Are you sure that in fact, the time is actually non-zero?  What is "ins"?

Comment: its for installation i get  day month year but i get 00:00:00 for hh:mm:ss

Answer (score 0):

This is wrong: `ins.to_char(dateDemande,'DD/MM/YYYY HH:MI:SS ')`. The TO_CHAR call must wrap the entire name, including the table alias.  So do this:

```
to_char(ins.dateDemande,'DD/MM/YYYY HH:MI:SS ')
```

Same for `dateStatut`.